# How can I use Google Maps Circle, Rectangle and Polygon in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Anyone knows if I am able to user Google Maps Circle, Rectangle and Polygon classes in Node JS? In the frontend is easy with Google Maps Javascript SDK, but I can't figure out how to get a hold of this library within Node JS.

I need to be able to check if points are with bounds, something in the lines of:

```
    const location = google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: area.center,
        radius: area.radius,
    });
    const doesContain = circle.getBounds().contains(location);
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Getting the bounds of a circle will return a square area, certainly not a good way to check whether a point lies within the circle area. That said, you should know your circle radius (or be able to get it) and based on that distance, you should be able to tell if a point is *contained* in a circle by comparing the circle radius with the distance between the point and the circle center. For example: radius is 200m, point is at 250m from circle center - point is not within the circle area.

Comment: Good call, thanks, I totally missed it. I decided to create my own functions, they are posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Alright boys, after giving some thought I realized it's easier to create my own code for checking if a geometry contains a point than depend on Google Maps library to do so.

Although this does not offer and the functionality Google Maps SDK offers, it does solve the geometry problem.

For anyone else looking for other Google Maps SDK functionalities, checkout this [Node.js Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js). Though it does not include the geometry functions I was looking for.

## Solution

Without further ado here is my code:

```
class Circle {

    /**
    * Circle constructor
    * @param {array} center Center coordinate [lat, lng]
    * @param {number} radius Radius of the circle in meters
    */
    constructor(center, radius) {
        this.name = "Circle";
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /**
    * Checks if a point is within the circle
    * @param {array} point Coordinates of a point [lat,lng]
    * @returns true if point is within, false otherwhise
    */
    contains(point) {
        const { center, radius } = this;
        const distance = this.distance(center, point);
        if (distance > radius) return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * Calculate the distance between two points (in meters)
    * @param {array} p1 [lat,lng] point 1
    * @param {array} p2 p1 [lat,lng] point 2
    * @returns Distance between the points in meters
    */
    distance(p1, p2) {
        var R = 6378.137; // Radius of earth in KM
        var dLat = (p2[0] * Math.PI) / 180 - (p1[0] * Math.PI) / 180;
        var dLon = (p2[1] * Math.PI) / 180 - (p1[1] * Math.PI) / 180;
        var a =
            Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos((p1[0] * Math.PI) / 180) *
                Math.cos((p2[0] * Math.PI) / 180) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d * 1000; // meters
    }
}

class Rectangle {

    /**
    * Rectangle constructor
    * @param {arrar} sw South-west coorodinate of the rectangle [lat,lng]
    * @param {array} ne North-east coordinate of the rectangle [lat, lng]
    */
    constructor(sw, ne) {
        this.name = "Rectangle";
        this.sw = sw;
        this.ne = ne;
    }

    /**
    * Checks if a point is within the reactangle
    * @param {array} point Coordinates of a point [lat,lng]
    * @returns true if point is within, false otherwhise
    */
    contains(point) {
        const { sw, ne } = this;
        const x = point[0];
        const y = point[1];

        if (x < sw[0] || x > ne[0] || y < sw[1] || y > ne[1]) return false;
        return true;
    }
}

class Polygon {

    /**
    * Polygon constructor
    * @param {array} points Array of vertices/points of the polygon [lat,lng]
    */
    constructor(points) {
        this.name = "Polygon";
        this.points = points;
    }

    /**
    *
    * @returns {obj} Returns the coordinate of the min/max bounds that surounds the polygon
    *                (south-west coordinate, north-east coordinage as in [lat,lng] format)
    */
    getBounds() {
        const { points } = this;
        let arrX = [];
        let arrY = [];

        for (let i in points) {
            arrX.push(points[i][0]);
            arrY.push(points[i][1]);
        }

        return {
            sw: [Math.min.apply(null, arrX), Math.min.apply(null, arrY)],
            ne: [Math.max.apply(null, arrX), Math.max.apply(null, arrY)],
        };
    }

    /**
    * Checks if a point is within the polygon
    * @param {array} point Coordinates of a point [lat,lng]
    * @returns true if point is within, false otherwhise
    */
    contains(point) {
        const x = point[0];
        const y = point[1];
        const bounds = this.getBounds();

        // Check if point P lies within the min/max boundary of our polygon
        if (x < bounds.sw[0] || x > bounds.ne[0] || y < bounds.sw[1] || y > bounds.ne[1])
            return false;

        let intersect = 0;
        const { points } = this;

        // Geofencing method (aka Even–odd rule)
        // See more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule
        // Now for each path of our polygon we'll count how many times our imaginary
        // line crosses our paths, if it crosses even number of times, our point P is
        // outside of our polygon, odd number our point is within our polygon
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            // Check if pont P lies on a vertices of our polygon
            if (x === points[i][0] && y === points[i][1]) return true;

            let j = i !== points.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;

            // Check if Py (y-component of our point P) is with the y-boundary of our path
            if (
                (points[i][1] < points[j][1] && y >= points[i][1] && y <= points[j][1]) ||
                (points[i][1] > points[j][1] && y >= points[j][1] && y <= points[i][1])
            ) {
                // Check if Px (x-componet of our point P) crosses our path
                let sx =
                    points[i][0] +
                    ((points[j][0] - points[i][0]) * (y - points[i][1])) /
                        (points[j][1] - points[i][1]);
                if (sx >= x) intersect += 1;
            }
        }
        return intersect % 2 === 0 ? false : true;
    }
}

module.exports = { Circle, Rectangle, Polygon };
```

## Explanation

The Circle and Rectangle class is pretty straight forward, it's trivial to determine if a point lies within a boundary. The Polygon class is a bit more complicated because of obvious reasons.

The method used here to determine if a point P is within a polygon is called Geofencing (aka Even–odd rule), a common method in geospacial analysis.

#### Step 1

First we check if the point P falls within the max/min boundaries of the polygon (image 1), if it doesn't, we return false, problem solved.

[image]

**Image 1** -- Polygon boundaries, P1 is within the polygon boundaries, P2 is not.

#### Step 2

Then we check if the point lies on a vertices (points) of the polygon, if it does, we return true, problem solved. (Image 2)

[image]

**Image 2** -- Polygon boundaries, point P is on a vertices, return true.

#### Step 3

This next step is the most gratifying one, by now we know the point is with the polygon boundaries (from step 1) but we don't know if it's within it or not. The way to solve this we cast an imaginary line departing from the point to any direction, if it crosses the path of polygon even number of times, the point is outside of the polygon, if it crosses an odd number of times, the point is within the polygon. Like so:

[image]

**Image 3** -- An imaginary line from P1 crosses the polygon paths an odd number of times (3 times), it's within the polygon boundaries. A imaginary line from P2 crosses an even number of times (4 times), it lies outside of the polygon.

Since we can pick any direction we want to cast the imaginary line from, we'll pick along the x-axis to simplify things, like so:

[image]

**Image 4** -- Casting the imaginary line from point P parallel to the x-axis t0 simplify determining how many times it intersects our polygon.

To determine how many times the imaginary line intersects our polygon, we have to check each path of the polygon at a time. To do this, we break it down into two steps (see image 5 for references):

1. For each segment/path of the polygon we check if our point Py (y-component of our point P) is within the the boundaries of the path in question (Y1 and Y2). If it is not, we know our point is does not intersects that specific path and we can move on to the next one. If it is within the path's y-boundaries, then we have to check if it crosses our path in the x-direction (next step).
2. Assuming the step before is true, to check intersection in the x-direction we have calculate the equation for the path (using line equation: `y2 - y1 = m(x2 - x1)`) and plug in our Py component to solve for our intersection (in my code I call this Sx). Then we check if Sx is greater than Px, if so, then our imaginary line intersects the path in the x positive direction.

It's important to note that the imaginary line starts at our point P and we only count intersections in that direction we originally picked, in this case x-axis+. This is why Sx has to be grater than or equal to Px, otherwise the test fails.

[image]

**Image 5** -- We break down each path of the polygon to determine the number of intersections.

Once this path is done we move to the next one and so on. In this case the line crosses 3 times our paths, and therefore we know it's within our polygon.

This is a very clever and simple way if you think about it, it works for any shape, it's truly amazing.

## Read more

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule

## Examples

#### Example 1 - Simple shapes

```
const p = new Polygon([
  [-3, 3],
  [-4, 1],
  [-3, 0],
  [-2, -1],
  [0, 0],
  [3, 2],
  [0, 1],
  [-1, 4],
]);

console.log("Contains: ", p.contains([-1, 1])); // returns true
```

[JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/245xjqgy/3/)

[image: Example 1]

### Example 2 - Complex shapes (overlapping areas)

This method works for more complex shapes, when the polygon coordinates creates overlappping areas and they cancel each other out.

```
const p = new Polygon([
  [-2, 0],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 4],
  [-2, 4],
  [-2, 0],
  [0, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [0, -2],
  [-2, 0],
]);

console.log("Contains: ", p.contains([0, 1])); // returns false
```

[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/245xjqgy/4/)

[image]

## Side note

If you need to quickly plot points just to get a view of a shape/grid, this plotting tool helped a lot to get a visual of what's going on. Very often I thought my code had a bug when in fact my coordinates was skewed and code was correct.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator

I only wish it let you draw lines between points. Either way I found it helpful.

Comment: Good answer, well explained. I only tested the polygon and it seems to work. Interesting stuff. Have you tested it against *special cases*? More about it [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3502.pdf) and [here](https://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Hormann.2001.TPI.pdf).

Comment: Might be worth expanding your answer with short usage examples as it's not super clear from your code what your methods and constructors expect.

Comment: Also this won't take earth curvature into account which would be a problem with large scale polygons.

Comment: Thanks man! I tested on complex shapes and it works great,  As you suggested I posted some examples, more images, JSfiddles, good stuff. This was fun.

Comment: By the way, why would the curvature of Earth influence if a point is within boundaries? We're not dealing with distances and measures, just points within coordinates. Would it?

Comment: With this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/y04fadkh/), the green Polygon is non [geodesic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolylineOptions.geodesic), and the red Polygon is geodesic. Point `A` would be inside the non-geodesic Polygon, and point `B` would be outside. The opposite would be true with the geodesic Polygon. Yet, both Polygons have the same coordinates.

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah, that makes sense. How would one adjust for that? It can't be an easy feat since Earth isn't a perfect circle, right?

Comment: Indeed, I doubt there is an easy way to calculate that. You might find available libraries though. Maybe [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-geodesicUtils.html)?